# Django: How can I serve an angular app without using STATIC_URL during development?

Tags: django, angularjs, django-rest-framework

I have a django project which is making use of `django-rest-framework` to provide an api for an angular client.

The entire angular app is developed separately to the django project, and doesn't make use of any django templates or suchlike.

Eventually the angular app will be served as a static asset via nginx or something along those lines.

However, during development, I would like the django development server to serve the angular app.

The issue I have is that none of the static assets in `index.html` are prefixed with `STATIC_URL` or a similar *static* prefix which django can look for.

Attempting to serve all non-api routes as static files as such:

```
urlpatterns += static(r'', document_root=settings.ANGULAR_APP_ROOT)
```

gives an exception

```
Empty static prefix not permitted
```

I know that in nodejs express server you can use something like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'app')));
```

which works seamlessly. I guess it searches for any paths in the configured folder and if any match the requested url, serves them.

I do not want to force django specific code/prefixes into the angular app (ala `STATIC_URL` etc)

What I'm looking for is some middleware which will offer a fallback route for anything unmatched by the existing `urlpatterns` and search a filesystem path for a matching asset and serve it if found.

**Is it possible to get the static assets served like this with the django development server?**